# How can I get ASPX specific Intellisense and highlighting for files with custom extensions?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I'm working with a codebase for a large number of websites which contains files with a custom extension that are essentially *.aspx files. Size and complexity of the project, among other things, prevent me from simply renaming them to *.aspx permanently.

Setting `Options->Text Editor->File Extension` to use `HTML (Web Forms) Editor`, or to other providers in the list, for the custom file extension, and reopening the file can improve some things at the cost of others, but does not give the same results as renaming the file to `*.aspx`.

If I rename the file to *.aspx and re-open it, I instantly get syntax highlighting, intellisense, type-checking etc as expected.

**How can I get this to work with my custom file extension?**

Is there a way to force the file extension parameter into the `HTML (Web Forms) Editor` parser?

Is what I want even possible without writing a custom extension for VS?

---

Example of typical file layout:

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="True" %>

    <%@ Import Namespace="System.Collections.Generic" %>
    <%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>

    <!--other imports-->


    <script runat="server">

    //c# code

    </script>

    <!-- js code and/or html with <%=mOutput%> blocks -->
```

---

Non-exhaustive list of superficially related SO questions I read that didn't resolve this issue:

- [MVC Razor view Intellisense broken in VS 2013/2015/2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22832435/mvc-razor-view-intellisense-broken-in-vs-2013-2015-2017?rq=1)
- [Visual Studio 2010: force syntax highlighting / intellisense for specific file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13230631/visual-studio-2010-force-syntax-highlighting-intellisense-for-specific-file)
- [Fix formatting of aspx file in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978049/fix-formatting-of-aspx-file-in-visual-studio/4991917)
- [Visual Studio: Defining File Type Regardless of File Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12133034/visual-studio-defining-file-type-regardless-of-file-extension)

Comment: I'm getting this issue on files that are already aspx pages.  Everything between the <script> tags is white.  No syntax highlighting, intellisense, type checking, precompiler, etc.